# try / catch block fails and application crashes

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have the following code

```
try { 
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr = *((LPIN_ADDR)*hostEntry->h_addr_list); //fails
    clientService.sin_port = htons(port);
    }

catch (...) { return; }
```

If I disable my network adapter, my application crashes. Isn't such errors supposed to be caught?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a guess but you probably haven't checked `hostEntry` after `gethostbyname` returned and you got a NULL-pointer. Check it if it's null before using it.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Fixed now.

Comment: @coolface - make sure your code checks *all* sockets API return codes, or you are in for a long and painful few weeks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set VS right, then it will not catch SEH exceptions like access violations, although it IS possible to set it to catch SEH exceptions in catch(...) blocks. It's probably just a better idea to not exhibit the problem in the first place, SEH exceptions are usually an indicator that you did something seriously wrong.

Comment: So in this case, how do I make it check if I don't have a network adapter enabled so I don't get the SEH exception?

Comment: +1 - you need to do this, as well as make sure the code is set up for not just C++ exceptions.

Comment: @coolface - if you really want to check that you can use the IP Helper API.  Probably as simple as checking for an error on `gethostbyaddr` or wherever `hostentry` came from, though.

Comment: there's a reason this is disabled by default. It's generally a better idea to use C++ exception handling to handle C++ exceptions *only*. Use the appropriate SEH handlers for handling SEH exceptions (`__try`/`__except`) -- but yeah, better still is to write your code correctly so this error never occurs ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to reach a firm conclusion here without more code, but I imagine that `hostEntry` or its `h_addr_list` field is `NULL` due to the network being unavailable.  Your code only handles C++ exceptions and you would need to enhance it to [handle structured exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681409%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (such as access violation) in order for this to do what you expect.

Preferably, just fix the code so it does not use invalid pointers after an earlier error on `gethostbyaddr` *et al* (you should probably do this anyway, regardless of any exception handling enhancements).

Comment: If `h_addr_list` is NULL it wouldn't cause problems at this point.

Comment: @terminus - the line of code that's highlighted as failing dereferences that value into `sin_addr`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, did not see that one.